# Remove or hide option from react-select dropdown

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a list of 3 status that should be shown as the default value but I need to remove one of those options from the dropdown. I was able to disable it using the isOptionDisabled prop but my goal is to remove.

Right now I have an object with the option

```
export const userStatus = [
  { label: 'Active', value: 'ACTIVE' },
  { label: 'Blocked', value: 'BLOCKED' },
  { label: 'Pending', value: 'ACTIVATION_PENDING', isDisabled: true },
];
```

I want to remove the pending from the dropdown but show as default value if it is the default value.

My select component looks like this

```
<Select
      name={name}
      fullWidth={fullWidth}
      components={{ DropdownIndicator }}
      isSearchable={false}
      value={selectValue}
      options={options}
      classNamePrefix="styled-select"
      variant={variant}
      isDisabled={disabled}
      hasError={hasError}
      onChange={onSelectChange}
      isOptionDisabled={isOptionDisabled}
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you filter the options before you send it as a prop to React-Select?

Comment: If I filter that option from the options it won't show as default value